# My activity_main.xml launching not a design, this is the error occured

Tags: android

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@5cb55f83
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
    at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:7101)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.drawableStateChanged(AppBarLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's happening here without some code. It appears the issue is with `ObjectAnimator`, do you have any anim resources?

Comment: Not easy to find the issue without code, so pls put your code here.